# Curl request does not put json in index

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to index some sample data In windows I am using the curl.exe program and here is the command I use:

```
curl.exe -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/super_client/customer/1" -d '{
  "_id": "my_cust.client.12345",
  "client_oid": "12345",
  "client_name": "Taz",
  "flags": "['C2','C2','C3']",
  "user_ids": "1234567"
}'
```

The JSON is valid after checking in an online json validator. The request gets a `400`.
BTW, it did create the index with the proper columns. Didn't load the data though...

```
{
  "error": "MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@146c2f2; line: 1, column: 8]]; ",
  "status": 400
}
```

Is this something related to windows? Am I using the wrong PUT request format for indexing data to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your quotes are improperly nested.  You need to escape inner quotes of the JSON argument (`-d`).

```
"{\"_id\": \"my_cust...
```

It may also be easier to wrap that string in single quotes too (`'{"_id":...`) but you will end up with nested single quotes as well because of `flags`.  Not sure why that has to be a string instead of an array, though.

Comment: Ughh windows.. Thank you Explosion Pills

Comment: @ImtiazAhmad this has nothing to do with windows; you would have to do the same thing in unix